# Repeating output of an array

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
    $timein_out = $this->time_model->get_timein_out($this->input->get('i'));   

    $total_diff= array();
    $hours = array();
    $mins =array();

    foreach($timein_out as $timetest)
     {
        $total_diff[] = strtotime($timetest["Time_out"]) - strtotime($timetest["Time_in"]);

        for($key=0;$key<count($total_diff);$key++)
        {
            $hours[] = intval(floor($total_diff[$key]/3600));
            $mins[] =  intval(($total_diff[$key]-$hours[$key]*3600)/60); 
        }

     };

     echo json_encode($total_diff); // output: [33600,34560,35160]
     echo json_encode($hours); // [9,9,9,9,9,9]
     echo json_encode($mins); //[20,20,36,20,36,46]
```

The actual output should be

```
 echo json_encode($hours); // [9,9,9,]
 echo json_encode($mins); //[20,36,46]
```

Question: Why is the output repeating? what is the problem in my code? :( thanks.

Comment: what is the value of `$timein_out`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

may be you want the inner loop outside. try this.

```
 foreach($timein_out as $timetest)
 {
    $total_diff[] = strtotime($timetest["Time_out"]) - strtotime($timetest["Time_in"]);

 }
 for($key=0;$key<count($total_diff);$key++)
 {
     $hours[] = intval(floor($total_diff[$key]/3600));
     $mins[] =  intval(($total_diff[$key]-$hours[$key]*3600)/60); 
 }
```

Comment: +1 better approach than the accepted answer.its run for 2n times and accepted answer runs for n*n times....

Comment: yeah.. i think this one is faster than the other one.. :)

Answer (score 1):

may be try [unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)'ting the `$total_diff` like:

```
foreach($timein_out as $timetest) {
    $total_diff[] = strtotime($timetest["Time_out"]) - strtotime($timetest["Time_in"]);

    for($key=0;$key<count($total_diff);$key++) {
        $hours[] = intval(floor($total_diff[$key]/3600));
        $mins[] =  intval(($total_diff[$key]-$hours[$key]*3600)/60); 
    }
    unset($total_diff);
}
```

Comment: sorry dude i think the other one is much faster.